# Run native executable in Android

Tags: adb, bluestacks

When I install FaceNiff on Bluestack and try to run the executable file from adb shell by

./FaceNiff

I get the error:

/system/bin/sh: ./FaceNiff: not executable: magic 7F45

I have rooted the phone, su the adb.
I think i need correct su and busybox. I tried but failed.

Comment: and where did you get this FaceNiff executable from? If it was compiled for GNU/Linux, it won't run on Android.

Comment: Why do you try to run it from the shell? Isn't it a normal APK?

Comment: I downloaded it from faceniff.ponury.net; faceniff.apk has the binary in asset folder. trying to Reverse Engineer it to understand how ELF is called on android.

Comment: I am using Bluestack. I am getting the same error even when i try to run IDA android_server {rooted, updated su-x86, busybox-i686}

Comment: a reverse engineer without understanding the difference between ARM and x86 ABI? you have got a lot to learn

Comment: trying man... maybe pointing out a right direction be more helpful

Comment: Finally i understood. Bluestacks is based on Android-x86 and the file is ARM-based; that is why the error. Tanks anyways

Answer (score 6):

7F45 are the first two bytes of the ELF header `\x7FELF`. Android also uses ELF, so the error message you encounter means that the FaceNiff binary is not recognised as executable by your kernel (unlikely, unless you forgot to `chmod +x` it), not for your architecture (e.g. x86 instead of ARM), or uses a dynamic linker not included (e.g. glibc or µClibc instead of Bionic).

If you need to run an Android-ARM executable on Android-x86 you must recompile it for x86 (and look for the correct bitness too, 32-bit vs. 64-bit is also different).

Disclaimer: I’m the [`mksh`](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) maintainer.